# Jquery ajax like and dislike button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Guys am trying to create like and dislike button like on fb. I have list of posts which I list looping in PHP. I just want one button if liked set Blue color, if is not liked set normal (default) color. 
All likes records are stored in db 
**id | account_id | item_id | etc..**

I have one php controller for likes which holds 2 main methods
**addAction()** and **deleteAction()** . First and second action only accept ajax request and add and delete records in database.

So my problem is when I click on that one button color is not changed when ajax finishes (success and complete). I think I do that fine but in wrong way. When 
I click on Like record is saved but live color changed. I also try with Jquery **load()** but I only can load all posts and after **setInterval** he returns me on the top of post list :/

Here is my jquery for this:

```
// Submit post like
submitPostLike: function() {

    var likes = 0;
    var likeBtn = $(".like-btn");

    likeBtn.click(function() {

         var postId = $(this).attr("rel");

        $.ajax({
             type: "post",
             cache: false,
             url: baseurl + "/like/addAction",
             data: {
                 item_id: postId,
             },
             success: function(response) {
                 console.log("post liked -" + postId); // debug
             },
            complete: function() {
                $(".like-txt").css("color", "blue");
                setTimeout(Post.updatePostList(), 1000);
                console.log("scheduler fired"); // debug
            },
             error: function(response, s, e) {
                alert(response.responseText);
             },
         });
     })
},
```

Delete Action is the some I don't put it.

Html which is created over looping in php

```
<?php if(hasLiked($post->post_id, $acc_id)): ?>
     <button type="button" id="post_like_btn" rel="<?= $post->post_id;?>" class="dislike-btn btn btn-xs btn-default">
     <div class="like-txt"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Like </div>
     </button>
<?php else : ?>
   <button type="button" id="post_dislike_btn" rel="<?= $post->post_id;?>" class="like-btn btn btn-xs btn-default">
  <i class="like glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Dislike
  </button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**hasLiked()** is php function with checking if that post already liked by this account. If account's like exists in db show dislike button.

Now how live refresh like with load() function when someone like post? All this works but like text is blue only when I refresh page.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML is being processed on the server side and served to the client. If `hasLiked` returns false, the div with class `like-txt` will not be present in the HTML served. Hence, when you try to access it in the `complete` method of the Ajax call, nothing happens. You would need to make the element present in the Dom, whether the value returned by `hasLiked` is false or not. You can keep it hidden, but it needs to be part of the Dom.